# Append different content type (video and Image) in Ajax formData in same request Request in MVC

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have a simple form which contains few input of type files which accept images and video and strings. I just want to post the file save it in table as well as server.

**I am not able to get video type content at my controller.**

Can anyone help me regarding this, Thanks in advance.

I am writing the code in js

```
function getOfficeTypeDetails() {
        $('#submitOfficeDetails').click(function () {
            if (window.FormData !== undefined) {
                var OfficeTypeDetails = getOfficeTypeFormData();
                $.ajax({
                    url: '/Member/SetOfficeTypeDetails',
                    type: "POST",
                    contentType: false, 
                    processData: false, 
                    data: OfficeTypeDetails,
                    success: function (result) {
                        alert(result);
                    },
                    error: function (err) {
                        alert(err.statusText);
                    }
                });
            } else {
                alert("FormData is not supported.");
            }
        });
    }

function getOfficeTypeFormData() {  
    var officeTypeDetails = new FormData();

    var sketchFileUpload = $("#Sketch").get(0);
    var sketchFiles = sketchFileUpload.files; 
    for (var i = 0; i < sketchFiles.length; i++) {
        officeTypeDetails.append("Sketch", sketchFiles[i]);
    }

    var picturesFileUpload = $("#Pictures").get(0);
    var picturesFiles = picturesFileUpload.files; 
    for (var i = 0; i < picturesFiles.length; i++) {
        officeTypeDetails.append("Pictures", sketchFiles[i]);
    }

    var videoFileUpload = $("#Video").get(0);
    var videoFiles = videoFileUpload.files;
    for (var i = 0; i < videoFiles.length; i++) {
        officeTypeDetails.append("Video", videoFiles[i]);
    }
}
```

Mvc controller-

```
public ActionResult SetOfficeTypeDetails(OfficeTypeDetails model)
        {
     if (Request.Files.Count > 0)
            {
                HttpFileCollectionBase files = Request.Files;
                for (int i = 0; i < files.Count; i++)
                {
                    //string path = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "Uploads/";  
                    //string filename = Path.GetFileName(Request.Files[i].FileName);  

                    HttpPostedFileBase file = files[i];
                    string fname;

                    // Checking for Internet Explorer  
                    if (Request.Browser.Browser.ToUpper() == "IE" || Request.Browser.Browser.ToUpper() == "INTERNETEXPLORER")
                    {
                        string[] testfiles = file.FileName.Split(new char[] { '\\' });
                        fname = testfiles[testfiles.Length - 1];
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        fname = file.FileName;
                    }

                    // Get the complete folder path and store the file inside it.  
                    fname = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/UploadSketch/"), fname);
                    file.SaveAs(fname);
                }
}
```

Request PayLoad

> ------WebKitFormBoundaryAVR201VRxYZdZvvJ Content-Disposition: form-data; name="Sketch"; filename="P14-03_12.32.jpg" Content-Type:
>   image/jpeg
>
> ------WebKitFormBoundaryAVR201VRxYZdZvvJ Content-Disposition: form-data; name="Video"; filename="Baby Doll_ Ragini MMS 2 Sunny Leone
>   Song _ Meet Bros Anjjan Feat. Kanika Kapoor[1].mp4" Content-Type:
>   video/mp4
>
> ------WebKitFormBoundaryAVR201VRxYZdZvvJ Content-Disposition: form-data; name="MemberId"

Comment: use multipart/form-data if the form contains a file upload

Comment: still i am not able to post my video at controller...

Comment: what is the error now ?

Comment: I can get all the data either image file or or other field of data at my controller except video file.

Comment: I need to post image Video and other contents, I am able to get all the things except video at my controller.!

Comment: Hi, Try this if anyone reach on this question.
Try to increase size of the "upload_max_filesize"(i.e. Maximum allowed size for uploaded files) and "post_max_size"(i.e. Maximum allowed size that your post request can handle) in "php.ini"(If you are using PHP and Apache). 
By default these two settings have values 2M and 8M respectively. Increase value : upload_max_filesize = 60M and post_max_size= 61 (i.e. Must be greater than or equal to upload_max_filesize). Restart Apache and try to upload the file type of video.